# How can I allow single minus only with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I allow single hyphens only with preg_match?

My example thats does not work.

```
function isSubdomainValid($subdomain){
    $patt = '/^([a-z0-9]+-?[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9]+)+$/i';
    if (preg_match($patt, $subdomain)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For instance,

```
helloworld                   ok
hello-world                  ok
hello-world-again            ok
hello--world                 not ok
hello-world--again--         not ok
--hello-world--again         not ok
hello-world--again-          not ok
-hello-world-again           not ok
```

Comment: Your example code yields the desired results for all shown instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works Great!

```
function isSubdomainValid($subdomain){
    $patt = '/^([a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9]+)+$/i';
    $patt2 = '/-{2}/';
    if (preg_match($patt, $subdomain)){
        if (!preg_match($patt2, $subdomain)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $patt = '/^([a-z0-9](+-){0,}[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9]+)+$/i';
?>
```

try this 
source " http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html